# Laravel multi tabs control

Tags: php, laravel

Use laravel 7. After user login, it is saved in session variables(in database) and called usually using auth()->user(). After the login process is saved, the user can choose a company that is linked and carry out due processes. When linking to a company, it is also saved in the session variables. During the processes it is possible to open several browser tabs. The problem I'm facing occurs when the user opens several tabs already linked to a company, and when changing the company, (almost like a logoff, but they keep the data from auth()->user()) only the tab in which he made the alteration assume the new data, in the others, just forcing an update (entering another page or pressing f5). If the user is on a screen to post, for example, and change the company in another tab, when returning to the post screen, the information remains and when trying to post, it ends up causing errors.
Is there any way I can control this? My idea would be when selecting the company, some trigger fire so that the browser tabs update.

PS: This is not a multi auth. It's like auth()->user()->company->companyFunctions();

1. Attempting to use the reload with JavaScript, Jquery, but it does not update all tabs, just the one I make the request.
2. Any modification with migration, the session data is updated when I select the company, the other pages receive the data as soon as they update, that is, if you try something after selecting it, it automatically already has the new data.

Comment: PHP is a server side language - thus it is stateless from the client (browser). Thankfully, tools like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) exist. You can utilise Laravel's [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting) to dispatch these events and then listen to them on your front-end, with Javascript, to then handle the switch of companies in all your tabs.

Comment: It is not possible to change the company for all open tabs. Instead of this, you can check the selected company of the current page and from the session in middleware. If they are different, simply redirect to the same page or refresh the same page.

Comment: @SagarSainkar both $request->user() and auth()->user() brings the new selected company. Is there any other way?